# Routing CLI commands in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking for `gem` or idea on how to eleagntly route CLI commands in Ruby. `Thor` is solution that I am already using and it is great in sense that it allows you to build specific command line structure. Example:

```
person show 1               => Info about person Id 1
person show all             => Show all people
person delete 2             => Delete person with Id 2
```

`Thor` is great at this and I highly recommend it. Now I have a need for more semantic oriented CLI structure so for example:

```
show person 1                => Same as 'show person 1'
show people                  => Same as 'show person all'
etc...
```

`Thor` does not support this so I need to implement it. I will build layer above thor which would pre-process commands and send them to thor. I am looking best way to do it. I am hopping to avoid messy structure of `case/when/when...`. Thank you.

Comment: I am hopping for some to answer this with `cocaine gem` link saying: "I highly recommend cocaine!" :)

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend cocaine! https://rubygems.org/gems/cocaine

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this would be to create two executables: one is your current one `person`, that implements all the functionality.

The second one could be called something like 'person-app` and would be designed to be symlinked.  For example

```
> ln -s person-app show
> ln -s person-app delete
> whatever else
```

So, you now have several symlinks to the same app, `person-app`.  `person-app` can detect which symlink was used by examining `$0`, and then formulate a call to `person`:

```
case File.basename($0)
when 'show' then system("person show #{ARGV.join(' ')}")
when 'delete' then system("person delete #{ARGV.join(' ')}")
end
```

And so forth.  It's kinda hacky, but it should work and keep code duplication to a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Try `cliqr` https://github.com/anshulverma/cliqr. The README has a great use case example.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [console_runner](https://github.com/yuri-karpovich/console_runner) gem. The best thing about it you don't need to write new code. You can execute any existing Ruby file from command line. All you need is to add annotations ([YARD](https://yardoc.org/)-like syntax) to Class and methods you want to make executable:

```
# @runnable This tool can talk to you. Run it when you are lonely.
#   Written in Ruby.  
class MyClass

    def initialize
      @hello_msg = 'Hello' 
      @bye_msg = 'Good Bye!' 
    end

    # @runnable Say 'Hello' to you.
    # @param [String] name Your name
    def say_hello(name)
      puts @hello_msg + ', ' + name
    end

    # @runnable Say 'Good Bye' to you.
    def say_bye
      puts @bye_msg
    end

end
```

The gem will generate CLI interface for you.

```
$ c_run /projects/example/my_class.rb  --help
Options:
  --debug    Run in debug mode.

This tool can talk to you. Run it when you are lonely.
Written in Ruby.

Available actions:
        - say_hello
                Say 'Hello' to you.
        - say_bye
                Say 'Good Bye' to you.
```

You could *use parameters* as well. Run **MyClass#say_hello**:

```
$ c_run /projects/example/my_class.rb say_hello --name 'Yuri'
 -> Hello, Yuri
```

Run **MyClass#say_bye**:

```
$ c_run /projects/example/my_class.rb say_bye
 -> Good Bye!
```